How to package a micronaut application in a single jar without parent pom
I have a micronaut project where I do not inherit the pom, but I use dependency management instead:
<dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.micronaut.platform</groupId>
            <artifactId>micronaut-parent</artifactId>
            <version>4.4.2</version>
            <type>pom</type>
            <scope>import</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>

I expected that mvn package would still generate a single executable jar, but this does not seem the case: it generates a jar with just the project classes.
how can I trigger the mn plugin to shade the final jar?

I found out how to do it: just copy the configuration of the maven shade plugin from micronaut parent pom and attach its execution to the package phase. Something like:
<plugin>
   <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
   <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
   <version>3.6.0</version>
   <executions>
     <execution>
       <id>default-shade</id>
       <phase>package</phase>
       <goals><goal>shade</goal></goals>
       <configuration>
         <createDependencyReducedPom>false</createDependencyReducedPom>
         <transformers>
           <transformer implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.ManifestResourceTransformer">
           <mainClass>${exec.mainClass}</mainClass>
         </transformer>
         <transformer implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.ServicesResourceTransformer"/>
         </transformers>
         <filters>
           <filter>
             <artifact>*.*</artifact>
             <excludes>
               <exclude>META-INF/*.SF</exclude>
               <exclude>META-INF/*.DSA</exclude>
               <exclude>META-INF/*.RSA</exclude>
               <exclude>module-info.class</exclude>
             </excludes>
           </filter>
         </filters>
       </configuration>
     </execution>
   </executions>
 </plugin>

